# Unable to generate android skeleton project from sencha touch because of stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have downloaded sencha command  v4.0.4.84 , sencha touch2.4.0-commercial  and have installed ruby 1.9.3p545 and installed sass and compass and ant and installed jdk 1.7 and set classpath ,path successfully in my windows 7 64 bit machine.

PS : The problem i am facing is to Unable to generate android skeleton project from sencha touch example project.

**Steps I have tried**

1. Extracted the sencha touch 2.4.0 -commerical and then in the command prompt executed the following command

   **D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\FirstApp>sencha generate app firstApp ../FirstApp**

2) **Now I have copied the files of KitchenSink example from senchatouch and replaced (pasted) the contents in the FirstApp.**

3) Then executed the following command to refresh the app
    **sencha app refresh**

4) Then I have created keytool as shown below
    **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jjdk1.7\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\firstapp.keystore -alias san  -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

5) Now I have updated the content of packager.json and there i fed the certificate path and it's password and alias name and android sdk path .
Content of Packager.json

```
{
    /**
     * @cfg {String} applicationName
     * @required
     * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
     * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationName":"My Application",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} applicationId
     * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationId":"com.mycompany.myAppID",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} bundleSeedId
     * A ten character string which stands before aplication ID in Apple Provisioning Portal
     */
    "bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} versionString
     * @required
     * This is the version of your application.
     */
    "versionString":"1.0",

    /**
     * @cfg {Integer} versionCode
     * @required
     * This is the integer version code of your application, or you can refer to it as a build number. Used only for Android builds.
     */
    "versionCode":"1",

    /**
     * @cfg {Object} icon
     * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html
     *
     * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
     * http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html
     *
     * iOS 7 uses 60, 76, 120, 152 (29, 58 for the Settings app; 40, 80 for Spotlight search results).
     * iOS 6.1 and earlier uses 57, 72, 114, 144 (29, 58 for the Settings app, for Spotlight search results on iPhone; 50 and 100 for Spotlight search results on iPad).
     * Android uses 36, 48, 72, 96.
     * If you package for Android you can ignore iOS icons and vice versa.
     */
    "icon": {
        "60":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
        "120":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
        "76":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
        "152":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png",
        "36":"resources/icons/Icon-36.png",
        "48":"resources/icons/Icon-48.png",
        "96":"resources/icons/Icon-96.png",
        "57":"resources/icons/Icon-57.png",
        "114":"resources/icons/Icon-57@2x.png",
        "72":"resources/icons/Icon-72.png",
        "144":"resources/icons/Icon-72@2x.png",
        "29":"resources/icons/Icon-Small.png",
        "58":"resources/icons/Icon-Small@2x.png",
        "40":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-40.png",
        "80":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
        "50":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-50.png",
        "100":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-50@2x.png"
    },

    /**
     * @cfg {String} inputPath
     * @required
     * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
     */
    "inputPath":"./",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} outputPath
     * @required
     * This is where the built application file with be saved. Make sure that output path is not in your input path, you may get into endless recursive copying
     */
    "outputPath":"../build/",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} configuration
     * @required
     * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
     * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
     */
    "configuration":"Debug",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} platform
     * @required
     * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
     *  - iOSSimulator
     *  - iOS
     *  - Android
     *  - AndroidEmulator
     */
    "platform":"Android",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} deviceType
     * @required
     * This is device type that your application will be running on.
     *
     * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
     *
     * Available options are:
     *  - iPhone
     *  - iPad
     *  - Universal
     */
    "deviceType":"Universal",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificatePath
     * This is the location of your certificate.
     * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
     */
    "certificatePath":"D:/firstapp/touch-2.4.0-commercial/testapp/my-release-key.keystore",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificateAlias
     * This is the name of your certificate.
     *
     * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
     *
     * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
     * can just put "iPhone Developer".
     *
     * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
     */
    "certificateAlias":"san",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificatePassword
     * The password which was specified during certificate export
     */
    "certificatePassword":"san12345",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} provisionProfile
     * The path to the provision profile (APP_NAME.mobileprovision) which you can create and then download from Apple's provisioning portal
     */
    "provisionProfile":"",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} URLScheme
     * URL scheme for communication with your application, can be empty if you don't use custom URL scheme in your project.
     */
    "URLScheme":"",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} notificationConfiguration
     * Notification configuration for push notifications, can be "debug", "release" or empty if you don't use push notifications in your project.
     */
    "notificationConfiguration":"",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} sdkPath
     * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
     */
    "sdkPath":"C:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} androidAPILevel
     * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
     * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
     */
    "androidAPILevel":"17",

    /**
    /**
     * @cfg {Array[String]} permissions
     * Array of permissions that is used by an application (Android only) 
     * Full list of permissions for Android application can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
     */
    "permissions":[
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "CAMERA",
        "VIBRATE",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CALL_PHONE"
    ],

    /**
     * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
     * @required
     * This is orientations that this application can run.
     */
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

6) After that i have executed the following command 
    **D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\FirstApp>sencha app package build packager.json**

**All my android directortes i.e., android skeleton project  were created as you see can in the following picture**

[image]

Once I got the following error , all my android files structures were gone i m getting

stbuild exited with non zero error code:7

full stact trace:

```
D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\FirstApp>sencha app package build packager.js
on
Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84
[ERR]
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\src\com\mycompany\myA
ppID
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\src\com\mycompany\myAppID\ST
Activity.java
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\libs
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\values
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\values\strings.xml
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\layout
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\layout\main.xml
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\drawable-xhdpi
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\drawable-hdpi
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\drawable-mdpi
Created directory D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\res\drawable-ldpi
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\AndroidManifest.xml
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\build.xml
Added file D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\proguard-project.txt
A subdirectory or file ..\build\\\libs\ already exists.
A subdirectory or file ..\build\\\assets\ already exists.
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j
re7\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.0.1
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyApplication
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyApplication...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.2
[gettarget] API level:        17
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyApplication...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:11:
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with val
ue '@drawable/icon').

BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following err
or occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1

Total time: 2 seconds
""C:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk\tools\android" create project --target a
ndroid-17 --name MyApplication --activity STActivity --path "../build/\/" --pack
age com.mycompany.myAppID"
Could not run ant with error: 1
Failed to package application

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7

D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\FirstApp>
```

**Update**
Thanks to Mr.Martin for pointing in right direction , I have fixed the issue by adding the following line in packager.json **"iconName":"icon.png",**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build process fails, because it misses an icon. This is communicated by the following line:

```
[aapt] D:\firstapp\touch-2.4.0-commercial\build\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:11:
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with val
ue '@drawable/icon').
```

I haven't used Sencha Cmd to build a phonegap project yet (I use phonegap directly) so I have no idea which icon is missing or what names you have to provide in your packager.json file. 
But the error says that aapt is looking for an icon that is named 'icon.png'. You have not provided this icon in your packager.json.

Make sure that all icons are in your resources/icons folder and are named correctly.

Comment: I am not getting your point,icon.png, I am assuming that your are mentioning about these lines  "100":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-50@2x.png" in my packager.json, to change like this  "100":"resources/icon/Icon-Small-50@2x.png" , kindly let me know my understanding is correct, Thanks martin

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction, I have added the following line in my packager.json , then the issue is resolved and i got the apk file. "iconName":"icon.png", i have  updated the Question with answer.