# Generate Android apk from Sencha Touch using Sencha Cmd5 , No error , No output

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I have tried to generate **android apk from my sencha touch project** using **sencha cmd 4.0** ,

unfortunately I had faced the error **stbuild exited with non zero error code:3** , Since I did not get any meaning about this error code giving by stbuild in their sencha's offical site or internet  , I have planned to use sencha cmd 5.0.1.231 , As you know in Sencha Cmd 5.0 stbuild is no longer supported.

I have uninstalled and downloaded **Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231** ,**sencha sencha touch2.4.0-commercial**  and have installed **ruby 1.9.3p545** and installed **sass** and **compass** and **ant** and installed **jdk 1.7** and set classpath , path successfully in my windows 7 64 bit machine.

PS : The problem I am facing is I am Unable to generate android apk file from my sencha touch project using sencha cmd , actually it does not convey any errors.

**Steps I have tried**

1. Extracted the sencha touch 2.4.0 -commerical and generated the app using sencha generate command and created the sencha tocuh project and then I have writeen my model , view , controllers and stores

2) Then executed the following command to refresh the app
    **sencha app refresh**

4) Then I have created keystore  using traditional keytool command

5) Now I have updated the content of packager.json and there I fed the required information such as certificate path and it's password and alias name and android sdk path .

6) After that I have executed the following command 
    **sencha app build native**

**This command does not throws any errors but I did not find apk file in my project folders**

**full stact trace:**

```
    D:\myapp>sencha  app build native
    Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
    [INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
    [INF] Loading app json manifest...
    [INF] Concatenating output to file D:myapp\build\temp\production\App\sencha-compiler\cmd-packages.js
    [INF] writing content to D:myapp\bootstrap.js
    [INF] appending content to D:myapp\bootstrap.js
    [INF] appending content to D:myapp\bootstrap.js
    [INF] appending content to D:myapp\bootstrap.js
    [INF] Appending content to D:myapp/bootstrap.json
    [INF] Concatenating output to file D:\myapp\native\app.js
    [INF] merging resources into D:\myapp\native\resources
    [INF] merged 0 resources into D:\myapp\resources
    [INF] merging resources into D:\myapp\native\resources
    [INF] merged 0 resources into D:\myapp\native\resources
    [INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
    identical ../css/app.css
    [INF] Copying page resources to D:\myapp\native
    [INF] Generating file deltas to D:\myapp/deltas
    [INF] Writing content to D:\myapp\native/app.json
    [INF] Writing content to D:\myapp\native/microloader.js
    [INF] Appending content to D:\myapp/microloader.js
    [INF] Building output markup to D:\myapp\native/index.html
    [INF] Writing content to D:\myapp\native/index.html
    [INF] generating cache manifest to D:\myapp\native/cache.appcache

D:\myapp>
```

My Question is Is Cordova or Phonegap is mandatory for generating an android apk from sencha touch using sencha cmd 5 , because I did not use Cordova or Phonegap for generating android apk from sample Kicthensink sencha touch project using sencha cmd 4. as you can see  in my previous Question [Unable to generate android skeleton project from sencha touch because of stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25725750/424413).

Answer (score 2):

Finally I had solved the problem.

In Sencha Cmd5.x version there's no support for generating apk , we have to use either phonegap or cordova.

A Special **Thanks to loiane**, she clearly conveyed in her blog http://www.loiane.com/2013/06/integrando-sencha-touch-com-phonegap-hello-world/ , that we need to issue **sencha app build** instead of **sencha app build native** .

After that you can see under **build** directory in your sencha project , you will able to see the **production** folder , inside that **App** folder ( i.e, name of the Application , in my case it is app ) is there , **copy files and paste** the files in the **www** directory under **assets** directory in our **phone gap project** , **remember you should not remove cordova.js file from www directory.**

Then run your Phonegap application.